# How to install postgis on Postgres 15?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

i do not find a postgis package for postgres 15 on ubuntu. There are tons of blog posts out there showing all the same line:

```
sudo apt install postgis postgresql-x-postgis-3
```

`x` stand for the postgresql version.

But I do not find that package for postgres 15.1 (Ubuntu 15.1-1.pgdg18.04+1). Am I missing something, isn't it supported yet? Should one go for a lower postgres version?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: PostgreSQL packages are spelled out, including the **ql** at the end.

Comment: And what is with the 'x'?  Did you literally try to install the package spelled that way?  Whose instructions were you following?

Comment: search for postgresql-15-postgis-3

Comment: I did try `sudo apt install postgresql-15-postgis-3`

A simple `sudo apt-cache search postgis` shows me packages for version 14, but not 15.

Comment: postgresql-15-postgis-3 was not published for ubuntu 18.04: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1ot8dU-0012ZW-Ou@atalia.postgresql.org I'm guessing it's because this ubuntu release is close to EOL. Try to ask directly in the pgsql-pkg-debian mailing list: https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-pkg-debian/